# Logstash: How to install an external plugin

Tags: docker, logstash

For the past few days, I am stuck on relatively simple task.

I need to install this plugin, https://github.com/lukewaite/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs, onto my Logstash docker container as I am using Cloudwatch logs as an input.

The **Dockerfile** is as below:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:8.7.0

# Install the Cloudwatch Logs input plugin
RUN mkdir ./logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs

COPY logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs-1.0.3.gem ./logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs.gem
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
RUN DEBUG=1 bin/logstash-plugin install --no-verify

# Install the OpenSearch output plugin
RUN /bin/sh -c bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-elasticsearch

# Copy the Logstash configuration file
COPY logstash.conf /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf

# Run Logstash
CMD ["/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash", "-f", "/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf"]
```

My **Gemfile** (truncated):

```
# This is a Logstash generated Gemfile.
# If you modify this file manually all comments and formatting will be lost.

source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "logstash-core", :path => "./logstash-core"
gem "logstash-core-plugin-api", :path => "./logstash-core-plugin-api"
gem "atomic", "~> 1"
gem "builder", "~> 3"
.
.
.
gem "logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs", :path => "./logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs"
```

Notice the last line.

Everything seems to run well but it gets stuck at the logstash-plugin install part.

Any ideas? Am I installing this in the wrong way entirely? Tried everything and will highly appreciate some feedback.

Thanks